# Convert a list of two numbers to indices for an array

Tags: python, list, indices

Short version: Given a list with two elements `[i, j]`, how do I get the *i*, *j* -element of a 2d array instead of the *i*, *j* rows: `arr[[i,j]]` to `arr[i,j]`.

I've seen similar cases where `*list` has been used, but I don't entirely understand how that operator works.

Deeper context:

I have a function that returns a nested list, where each sub-list is a pair of indices to be used in an array:

```py
grid = np.full((3,3), 1)

def path():
   ...
   return [[i_1, j_1], [i_2, j_2], ...]

for i in path():
   grid[path()[i]] = 0
```

But since `path()[i]` is a list, `grid[path()[i]] == 0` sets two *rows* equal to zero, and not a single element. How do I prevent that?
While not stricly necessary, a faster solution would be preferable as this operation is to be done many times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing that is confusing you is the difference in mathematic notation and indexing 2D (or n-dimensional) lists in Python/programming languages.

If you have a 2D matrix in mathematics, called **X**, and let's say you'd want to access the element in the first row and first column, you'd write **X(1, 1)**.

If you have a 2D array, it's elements are lists. So, if you want to access the 1st row of an array called **X** you'd do:

```
X[0] # 0 because indexation starts at 0
```

Keep in mind that the previous statement returns a new *list*. You can index this list as well. Since we need the first column, we do:

```
X[0][0] # element in 1st row and 1st column of matrix X
```

Thus the answer is you need to successively index the matrix, i.e. apply chain indexing.

As for your original question, here is my answer. Let's say **a** is the 2-element list which contains the indices **i** and **j** which you want to access in the 2D array. I'll denote the 2D array as **b**. Then you apply chain indexing, the first index is the first element of **a** and the second index is the second element of **a**:

```
a = [0, 0]  # list with 2 elements containing the indices
b = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]  # 2D array in which you want to access b[0][0]
i, j = a[0], a[1]
print(b[i][j])
```

Obviously you don't need to use variables **i, j**, I just did so for clarity:

```
print(b[a[0]][a[1]])
```

Both statements print out the element in the 1st row and 1st column of **b**:

```
1
```